# How to read and delete int-redis:store-inbound-channel-adapter messages on each poll

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Using this basic configuration :

```
<int-redis:store-inbound-channel-adapter id="listAdapter"
    connection-factory="redisConnectionFactory"
    key="messages"
    channel="redisChannel"
    collection-type="LIST" 
    >
        <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" />
</int-redis:store-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Messages that are read and put to redisChannel are also left in Redis. Is there a way to read and delete messages from Redis at the same time and put them to redisChannel, using this configuration?
I can do it manually using scheduler and executing redis commands that I need, but that feels like hacking around spring integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<int-redis:store-inbound-channel-adapter>` returns the `RedisStore` object. In your case it is a `List` implementation. So, you can simple call `remove()` or `clear()` methods of `List`, when it is necesary for you.
Another technique to use [Transaction Synchronization Factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/redis.html#redis-store-inbound-channel-adapter), but I'm not sure that it help you, as you may use a `<splitter>` after your `<int-redis:store-inbound-channel-adapter>`. However you should place that `RedisStore` to headers before splitter.

**UPDATE**

According to your last comment:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="redisChannel">
     <int-groovy:script>
        def data = [] + payload
        payload.clear()
        data
</int-groovy:script>
</int:service-activator>
```

As far as our payload is a `RedisStoreList` we can simply copy it to another list, `clear()` it and return that new list. The `clear()` operation will be delegated to the Redis.

Comment: I have a part of application pushing data to the same list this redis inbound adapter is taking data from. So I need it to delete data from the list as soon as taking it and forwarding to the redisChannel.